# Understanding Operational semantics

Tags: semantics

I have this derivation

```
(b,σ)→false  (skip,σ)→σ

(if b then c;w else skip)→σ
```

(With the top line being the precondition and the bottom line the expression)

Does the expression mean:

If b is True, then do command c, else do w and skip,

or

If b is True, then do command c and command w, else skip.

The semi-colon in the middle is confusing me?!

Also, why don't I have to include c in the precondition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every operational semantics is different and the question specifies no context, so I can only guess at the answer.

I would parse `if b then c; w else skip` as `if b then {c; w} else skip`, that is, the second interpretation from the question. The derivation seems to be about the case that `b` is false, so `c` is not mentioned because if `b` is false, `c` is not executed. Instead, `skip` is mentioned because it's executed.

Answer (score 1):

This just answers part of your question, heowever: `c` is not included in the precondition because it does not depend on the precondition. I somehow cannot make sense of the `w` in the second line either. Furthermore, the question might be off topic as it is more about computer science than actual programming.